# Why c++ compiler provides its own default constructor

Tags: c++, oop, constructor

My Question is
when we create a object of any class in c++ then if we have not provided any type of constructor in our class then c++ compiler provides its own default constructor. So why compiler provides its own constructor.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: So you can construct the object. If you don't want it you can mark it as `private`, implement a different default constructor, or otherwise use `= delete` in C++11 or newer.

Comment: @orhtej2 That's about the copy constructor, not the default constructor.

Comment: So it can call default constructors of class members. Otherwise you have to add explicit constructors for simple classes like `struct C { std::string s; C() : s() {} };`

Comment: Likely C compatibility. A structure object in C can be default initialized without providing an initializer. Without implicit default constructors, the same C code will not be valid to a C++ compiler. C parity (to an extent) was a goal. There is some merit however to requiring c'tors being declared explicitly. But C++ is a product of its time(s).

Comment: Even if you write default constructor it still will generate code that calls all default constructors of class members, and this will be executed before your logic. So your question is not fully correct

Comment: @jenkas That is not correct. A user-defined default constructor will, like any other constructor, initialize the members with the initializers that the constructor's member-initializer-list specifies, falling back to the default member initializers if any and then falling back to default-initialization. No prior default-construction happens for class-type members.

Comment: @user17732522 Sure you right, but I talked about constructor and not about member initialization that you write before function body, and I think that questioner also means that

Comment: @jenkas A more reasonable interpretation of what the questioner means is that if no type of constructor is provided in the class definition, then the compiler generates a default constructor. For example, `class A {};` has a compiler-generated default constructor, while `class B{ B(int) {} };` does not (because we have provided a constructor that takes an `int` parameter).

Comment: Because C, basically. The paradigm of "construct a blank object, then initialize" is very common in low-level C code. It's horrifying in high-level OOP-style code, which should only allow objects to exist in a fully-defined state, but C isn't a high-level OOP language.

Answer (score 1):

I have not looked up any history on the matter, but here are some possible reasons:

If a default constructor was not implicitly defined, then the following would not compile:

```
struct X {
    std::string str;
};

//...

X x;
```

because `X` would not have a default constructor. You would instead need to write

```
struct X {
    std::string str;

    X() : str() {}
};

//...

X x;
```

which seems unnecessary cumbersome, when it is clear what was intended. And in contrast to initialization with arguments, this is a common use case with clear semantics.

---

Also, as long as the class is plain old data (POD), meaning that it is a class that would also be allowed as a C structure, then it was (and is) intended that C++ be (mostly) compatible with C. In C for example

```
struct X {
    int i;
};

//...

struct X x;
```

is allowed and so it should also be allowed in C++. If there wasn't a default constructor that default-initializes each member, then there would need to be special rules for such class and initialization to not need to call a constructor and just leave the members with indeterminate values. But the same rule should not be applied to class members which do have proper constructors, since it shouldn't be possible to leave a class type with class invariants in an indeterminate state.